# Почему не работает fetch()?

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors

Пишу в VS CODE / Live Server + xampp
Скрипт не получает текст, не знаю в чем дело.
Как будто запрос не проходит `response.ok` выдает `false`.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="text_getter">Базовый текст</p>
    <button id="button1">Загрузить текст</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```js
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function () {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/8ajax/get_text.php', {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.ok);
        })
        .catch(alert);
};
```

PHP

```
<?php

$names[0]="qwe";
$names[1]="qwe";
$names[2]="rwe";
$names[3]="rwer";
 
$json = json_encode($names);
echo $json;
?>
```

**UPD**
Это както связано с CORS. Перенес все вфайлы PHP JS и HTML на другой комп, а там ниче не работает. ппц.
Работает если **Response {type: 'cors'**

`**Response {type: 'cors'**, url: 'http://localhost:8080/8ajax/json.json', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}`

Comment: Какие ошибки в консоли? Возможно, неправильный путь, либо CORS блокирует.

Answer (score 0):

Oпечатка в

```
'http://127.0.0.1:8080/8ajax/get_text.php'
                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего дело было в кеше браузера(хром). В IE страница грузилась.
Что бы все работало, в настройках apach нужно прописать добавление заголовка Access-Control-Allow-Origin.